# Able to run programme in command promt but not through PHP system/exec command

Tags: java, php, linux

I can run one program in my shell (Linux), but executing the same command on the same PC with PHP (using `system` or `exec` commands) does not work.

I can execute simple commands using `system` command in PHP (like `ls` or `which Java`).

I changed the permission of particular folder/program, and used whole path for my files and program.

```
system("/usr/bin/java -jar  /pathforprogram/programe.jar -convert /pathtforinput/inputfile.txt -xtg outputfile.txt >optional.txt");
```

What can be the reason for this?

Comment: Are you logged in as normal user or as root when using the command line?

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: you're ignoring the return value. `$output = system($command, $exit_code)`. don't debug in the dark. if a function provides an option to get error information, USE IT.

Comment: user having sudo power  @dot_spot and in optional.txt i am getting " 1 "

Comment: @Marc ..I am Biology student. SO,I have little knowledge about programming so could you please explain in little detail what is exit code. I donot think there is some exit code for this programme.